# Private inheritance usage from client

Tags: c++

I had a question related to private inheritance in C++.
My question is based on a reference related to this page [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm).
(Under the heading "**But What If We Do Need To Inherit?**")

The case is point is I declare a base class with a public virtual function. Then I inherit base class under private inheritance and name it derived class. this is shown as below

```
    class base {
            public:
            base() {}
            virtual ~base() {}
            virtual void func_1() {
                cout<<"base func1"<<endl;
            }
            void func_t() {
                cout<<"base funct"<<endl;
                func_3();
            }
            private:
            void func_3() {
                cout<<"base func3"<<endl;
                func_1();
            }
        };

class derived: private base {
public:
    derived() {}
    ~derived() {}
    virtual void func_1() {
        cout<<"derived func1"<<endl;
    }
};

base* b = new derived;
b->func_t();
```

The above statements give error that base is an inaccessible base of derived. 
What do I do if I want to call the func_1 as part of above function call function of the derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` indicates that names and members are not accessible from outside. The conversation to a private base class is one occourrence. You can simply wrap this conversation into a member function to let it work:

```
class derived
  : private base {
public:
    // other stuff

    base* get_base() {
        return this;
    }
};

derived* d = new derived;
base* b = d->get_base();
b->func_t();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you inherit `base` as a private base class, this means that all public members of `base` (including `base::func_1`) will be private in derived. The compiler will complain when you declare `derived::func_1` as `public`.

If you need `derived::func_1` as public, then you should inherit `base` publicly. If you do not need it to be public, then you should declare `derived::func_1` as being private.

Comment: Hi, if you look at the link I made a reference to, he has inherited base privately and still virtual function in derived was public.

Comment: I didn't look in detail at it, but it still breaks encapsulation.